# Requests to local server using C++ curl

Tags: c++, curl, request

I've got a local server on port 1234, where I have a few endpoints.
From bash i can get values by using:

```
curl -v --noproxy localhost, localhost:1234/option_name -X GET
```

I wanted to replicate this command using curl lib in C++.
My code is:

```
enum RquestType {GET, POST};
std::string send_request(std::string port, std::string option_name, std::string value, RequestType type)
{
    auto handle = curl_easy_init();
    std::string returnData = "";

    if(handle)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "localhost, localhost:" << port << "/" << option_name
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_NOPROXY, ss.str());
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &returnData);

        if(type == GET)
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_GET, 1);
        }
        else if(type == POST)
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, 1);
        }

        auto ret = curl_easy_perform(handle);

        if(ret != CURLE_OK)
            std::cout << "curl_easy_perform() failed: " << curl_easy_stderror(ret) << "\n"
        curl_easy_cleanup(handle);
    }
    return returnData;
}

int main()
{
    // Empty request should send available options
    std::string ret = send_request("1234", "", "", GET);
    std::cout << ret;
}
```

When I use this code I got error that: 'URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL'. Do you know why, and how to fix my code?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set CURLOPT_URL.
Instead, you set CURLOPT_PROXY to "localhost, localhost:1234/option_name"

CURLOPT_URL should be the URL you are requesting (presumably localhost:1234/option_name). And you probably don't need CURLOPT_PROXY

Comment: There should be CURLOPT_NOPROXY I edited this just a minute ago.
With your changes it almost worked, but now it can't write to std::string.

Comment: Ok I needed to define write function now it works perfectly, thank you! :)